# Overleaf Offline Replacement

Tags: overleaf, offline

I was recently scared by a compile time out problem in Overleaf, one day before a deadline for a huge project. Since paying the subscrition for more compile time is not an option to consider given that offline free alternatives exist, I started searching for a replacement. I installed an entire MikTex distribution and experimented with different editors. The editors I tried were TexWorks and Texmakers. I struggled with both of them because I couldn't open my downloaded project from Overleaf and get that useful left bar that guides to every directory with every file and image.

Is there a way to configure those editors to get that same left bar ? 
Or is there another editor which uses it by default ?

I hope I was clear.

Comment: the left bar is a feature of the overleaf website, so no editor can have _that_ sidebar exactly. Although of course many editors (or just operating system utilities generally) have tools for navigating a directory structure.

Comment: I thought TeXstudio had a project structure viewer in the left pane, hasn't it?

Comment: @Skillmon Yes, TeXStudio has it

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103304/discussion-on-question-by-ludgero-himself-overleaf-offline-replacement).

Comment: I've moved the discussion element to chat: it's not directly linked to the request here

Comment: To me, this feels like a 'which IDE should I use' question, in which case all we can do is point to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides